# complex sql: include records from products table where value on join has isdeleted value set in joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a web service that feeds a mobile app.  For a variety of reasons I send data down to the app via the service with a query that joins products, category products and categories into a single record for each category the product is in:

```
 SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Products.ItemID, Products.ManufacturerID) AS RowNum,
         Products.ProductID, Products.ItemID, Products.ManufacturerID, Categories.CategoryID, Categories.CategoryName, CategoryProducts.CategoryProductID,  Products.ItemName, Products.Description, Products.Notes, 
                      Products.Dimensions, Products.BasePrice, Products.OrderMinimumQuantity, 
                      ContainerMinimumQuantity = 
                        CASE  COALESCE(Products.ContainerMinQty, 0)
                            WHEN 0 THEN Products.OrderMinimumQuantity
                            ELSE Products.ContainerMinQty
                        END 
                      , Products.OrderMultipleQuantity, Products.OnHandQuantity, 
                      Products.Category, Products.IntroDate, Products.BackOrderDate, Products.UPC, Products.PriceLevel1, Products.PriceLevel2, Products.PriceLevel3, 
                      Products.PriceLevel4, Products.PriceLevel5, Products.PriceLevel6, Products.PriceLevel7, Products.PriceLevel8, Products.PriceLevel9, Products.PieceBox, 
                      Products.Cubes, Products.UnitOfMeasure, Products.UDF1, Products.UDF2, Products.UDF3, Products.UDF4, Products.UDF5, Products.AdditionalImageCount, 
                     PhotoName= LOWER(Products.PhotoName),  Products.Discontinued, Products.ModifiedOn, 
                        CategoryProducts.IsDeleted, Products.PriceLevel10, Products.PriceLevel11, Products.PriceLevel12, Products.PriceLevel13, 
                      Products.PriceLevel14, Products.PriceLevel15, Products.PriceLevel16, Products.PriceLevel17, Products.PriceLevel18, Products.PriceLevel19, Products.PriceLevel20, 
                      Products.Weight, Products.DimensionsMetric, Products.Source, Products.InventoryStatus, Products.CatalogCode, Products.CatalogName, 
                       CategoryProducts.SortOrder
 JOIN
                Categories INNER JOIN
                      CategoryProducts ON Categories.CategoryID = CategoryProducts.CategoryID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      Products ON CategoryProducts.ManufacturerID = Products.ManufacturerID AND CategoryProducts.ItemID = Products.ItemID
WHERE     (Products.ManufacturerID = @ManufacturerID)
            AND 
            (Products.ModifiedOn > @tStamp OR  CategoryProducts.ModifiedOn > @tStamp)
) AS Products
    WHERE RowNum >= @StartRow AND RowNum <= @EndRow
```

This gives me all of my products flattened out including products that are not in any category, which is what I want.  The problem with this is if a product has been in a category and that category product has been deleted the IsDeleted flag is set on the single flattened record that comes down to the device.  This is an issue because the product itself has not been deleted BUT rather the category product but my device only sees a single record with the IsDeleted flag set to remove it.  So in this case I need both a row for the flattened product with the deleted information and also a row for this product as if it was not deleted so users could still search for this product on the device.

Hopefully I explained this clearly, I have been banging my head on this for a week.

Comment: Could you include a table definition and just enough sample data to see the issue.  If you could simplify the table definition to isolate out the particular case, that'd also help a LOT.

Comment: I actually got the query I need but now need to know how to do rows over

Comment: @Slee, if you have the query you need could you please add it as an answer here?  I'm looking at a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to see two rows, then I would expect to see a UNION ALL in the subquery.  I think you need to include all products as well as all non-deleted product categories.